# In application Simply Scan ver 3.18.2 under Lubuntu 15.10 after open app is comment " Failed to scan. Unable to connect to scanner."

Tags: networking, drivers, lubuntu, printing, scanner

Condition:

Lubuntu 15.10
Simple scan ver 3.18.2
Brother DPC7030

Program Simple Scan do not see scanner. Application message "Failed to scan. Unable to connect to scanner". In preferences app see scan source ===> Brother
DCP7030. In older version Lubuntu 15.04 or 14.10 no problem with scanning documents with Brother DPC7030.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a USB scanner? If so, check with `lsusb`. Also `sane-find-scanner`should give you output. If not, then try `scanimage -L`. Please refer to [here](http://robsworldoftech.blogspot.in/2010/09/canon-canoscan-lide-100-on-ubuntu-or.html), for the entire solution. Hope it helps, thanks.